# How to send submitted form from ionic app to my email?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic5

I am trying to create a contact form for my ion app where when the visitor clicks the send button, I want this data to be sent to my email. Do you know how I could do that? Thank you.

Comment: I think there is no way to send data directly to email from ionic form
so you can use google form to integrate with ionic form
and manage data through google sheat

Comment: Thank you, just because I am quite a beginner could you suggest me how I can use the google form to embed the ionic form and manage the data via Google Sheet?